# how can I iterate hash data object and store in SQLite database in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, httparty

I am working on JSON data. Fetching JSON data from URL using `httparty` gem works perfectly. Now I want iterate hash data object and store in SQLite database.

```
# HTTParty response
@sett = {
  "restaurant_name": "Restaurant 3",
  "address": "xyz address",
  "country": "United States",
  "currency": "USD",
  "client_key": "12345",
  "client_name": "Client 3"
}
```

I want to store this JSON data in the database like this:

```
+-----------------+---------------+
| meta_key        | meta_value    |
+-----------------+---------------+
| restaurant_name | abc restatant |
| country         | USA           |
| ...             | ...           |
+-----------------+---------------+
```

```
def index
  require 'httparty'

  @setting = HTTParty.get(
    'http://codekyt.in/froodle-wp/wp-json/data/v2/projects?client_key=12345',
    headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
  )
  @sett = @setting.parsed_response

  @sett.each_key do |key, value|
    m = Setting.new
    m.meta_data = key
    m.meta_value = value
    m.save
  end
end
```

It store but in the format of array not hash.

In the database,

```
t.string :meta_data
t.string :meta_value
```

Comment: You could use `t.json :meta_data` for json data store,

Comment: thank u so much @ray

Comment: Perhaps, it is valid for rails-5 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going wrong in your code example.

1. When you are looping through the hash you use [`Hash#each_key`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Hash.html#method-i-each_key). Which only loops through the keys, not the values.

   ```
   @sett.each_key do |key, value|
   #                         ^- will always be nil
   ```

   To correctly loop through key/value pairs use [`Hash#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Hash.html#method-i-each).
2. You are calling [`save`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) in void context. What happens when a record cannot be saved? Currently it sets an error on the setting record and returns `false`, but both the return value and errors are ignored. This means that if a record for some reason cannot be saved, it's simply ignored. You might want to use [`save!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save-21) instead to raise an exception in case of failure. Alternatively you can handle the `save` return value.
3. How do you know which records belong together? You're currently simply saving `meta_data` and `meta_value`. What happens when you save settings from more than one request?

   This issue could be solved by adding an association to an other model. Resulting in the code:

   ```
   request = Request.create!(url: url)

   @sett.each do |key, value|
     request.settings.create!(
       meta_data: key,
       meta_value: value
     )
   end
   ```

   Alternatively you could use manage this column by yourself like so:

   ```
   request_nr = Setting.maximum(:request_nr) || 0
   request_nr += 1

   @sett.each do |key, value|
     Setting.create!(
       request_nr: request_nr,
       meta_data: key,
       meta_value: value
     )
   end
   ```

If the above issues are resoved you can convert a set of records to a hash by doing the following.

```
# First you need to fetch the records that belong together.
Setting.where(request_nr: 1)
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Setting id: 1, meta_data: ...>, ...]>

# The above will result in an collection of records, however we only care 
# about the key/value. We can use `pluck` to get those values.
Setting.where(request_nr: 1).pluck(:meta_data, :meta_key)
#=> [["restaurant_name", "Restaurant 3"], ["address", "xyz address"], ...]

# The above array can be converted to a hash by simply calling `to_h` on it.
Setting.where(request_nr: 1).pluck(:meta_data, :meta_key).to_h
#=> { "restaurant_name" => "Restaurant 3", "address" => "xyz address", ... }
```

**References:**

I already provided most links in the answer itself. However here are some of the methods used in the code-blocks that aren't mentioned in the text.

- [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck)
- [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-to_h)

Answer (score 1):

In migration, add

```
def change
  add_column :settings, :meta_data, :json
end
```

Or in case of creating new table,

```
t.json :meta_data # storing meta_data & meta_value in your code
```

In `setting.rb` model,

```
serialize: :meta_data, JSON
```

And in your code, change as,

```
  @setting = HTTParty.get(
    'http://codekyt.in/froodle-wp/wp-json/data/v2/projects?client_key=12345',
    :headers =>{'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
  )
  Setting.create(meta_data: @setting.parsed_response)
```

Little changes regarding associated object to be saved in above can be done as per your situation